# Are two positive defined quadractic forms simultaneously diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, conic-sections, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices

Let $f$ and $g$ be quadratic forms in real variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$, suppose that $f $ and $g$ are positive defined, is true that $f$ and $g$ are simultaneously diagonalizable?

I know that $f$ and $g$ have matrix representation $A_f$ and $A_g$ symmetric and have all eigenvalues positive, the problem then is to show that $A_f$ and $A_g$ commutes, therefore they are simultaneously diagonalizable.

So the product of symmetrical matrix is again a symmetrical matrix iff they commute, so it will be true if I can show that $A_fA_g$ is symmetric.

Am I looking in the right direction, where does the hipotesis of positive defined comes to play? There is a simplier way or a counterexample?

Comment: Did you look for related questions on MSE? Did you try to google your question?

Comment: I've found the ansewer later, the first time I couldnt find here the ansewer, but later I found. I'll close the question

Comment: Your "positive defined" should presumably be "positive definite".